# string iterator is not dereferencable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using a library to parse .pgn file, and when I tried to run the project I found this error:Debug Assertion Failed! program: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110D.dll File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring
Line:79
Expression:string iterator not dereferencable
For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the visual C++ documentation on asserts.

the problem is that when the iterator reaches to the end of the file, it points to nothing (start iterator (itr1) == end iterator (itr2)), I tried to add conditions to check if itr1 reached to the end of the file but it was useless.
So please tell me where is my fault.
here is my code source.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <PGNGameCollection.h>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream pgnfile("sample.pgn");
    pgn::GameCollection games;
    pgnfile >> games;
    std::cout << "the file sample.pgn contains " << games.size() << "games"     << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the class function that causes the error:

```
bool pgn::Parser::getComment(std::string::const_iterator &itr1, const std::string::const_iterator &itr2, pgn::CommentText &out)
{
    std::string::const_iterator local_itr=itr1;
    std::string comment;
    if(*local_itr != '{')
        return false;
    local_itr++; //skipping '{'

    while((*local_itr != '}') && (local_itr != itr2))
    {
        comment += *local_itr++;
    }
    local_itr++; //skipping '}'
    skipBlanks(local_itr, itr2);
    itr1=local_itr;
    out=pgn::CommentText(comment);
    return true;
}
```

skipBlanks function:

```
void pgn::Parser::skipBlanks(std::string::const_iterator &itr1, cost std::string::const_iterator &end)
{
    while((itr1 != end) && (isspace(*itr1)))
    {
        itr1++;
    }
}
```

I have searched stackoverflow and google for all similar problems but I could not find the answer. also I traced the code line by line until I have reached to the function that caused the error.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I have already debugged the code line-by-line before asking here, but I could not find the answer!

Comment: Then you probably use the debugger in a wrong way.

Comment: using the debugger helped me reach the function that caused the error but I could not fix it. I am using  a library which is not written by me and I tried to edit it to solve the error but I could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `itr2` is your end-iterator, then you must check your iterator for the end-condition *before* trying to dereference it

```
while((local_itr != itr2) && (*local_itr != '}'))
```

You are doing it the other way around, which would definitely lead to the problem you described.

It might also make sense to add checks for end-condition at the very beginning of your function, since there you are also dereferencing `local_itr`.

Also, if your cycle terminated because `local_itr` reached `itr2`, and there's nothing at `itr2` and after it, then the code after the cycle makes no sense. You are not allowed to increment `local_itr` in that situation.

Comment: I tried this, but the same error message appeared with Expression: string iterator not incremental

Comment: @Norhan Foda: Um... The same? How is it the same? You quoted your original error as "string iterator is **not dereferencable**" and now you get "**not incrementable**". The "not incrementable" is a completely different  error, which comes from your attempt to do `local_itr++` after the cycle. The latter makes no sense if you reached the end. This is a different problem, which would require a separate fix. Don't attempt to increment your iterator or read anything from it if it already reached the end.

Comment: I checked if the iterator reached to the end like this: if(itr1 != itr2){local_itr++;} so local_itr will be incremented only if it is not the end of the file. this takes me back to string iterator not dereferencable.

Comment: @Norhan Foda: Yes, it probably will "take you back", but to a different spot, which you are not showing us. You probably still have great many places in your code where you forget to check the end-condition *before* trying to dereference the iterator, i.e. same error as in your original code. (For example, what happens inside `skipBlanks`?). You will have to find all such errors and fix them one by one.

Comment: Believe me I tried to check all places in the code, if there is a method that allows me to upload the whole file so you can check it please tell me how to do.

Comment: I added skipBlanks function to see what happens inside it

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay .. the problem is solved, I put condition in every place in the code that uses string iterator. Then I discovered that when the file ends, itr1 still contains "\n\n" which causes the error, so I used skipBlanks first at the start of the called function to remove any spaces. this removed "\n\n" then put the condition to check if itr1 == itr2 == "" stop reading from the file else continue reading .... Finally it worked ... Thanks a lot for your great help